# Does |-x+3| equal x-3?

Tags: absolute-value

I'm not sure how to solve absolute values. How do I find the value of an absolute value.

Here are some examples:
Does |-x+3| equal x-3?
Does |x+3| equal x+3?

Comment: you must do case work

Comment: Without knowing the value of $x$ you can not find the value of it. I.e. you can not write it any simpler than you currently have it. Also using the word `solve` implies you have an equation. Is that what you meant when you said `solve absolute values`? If so please give an example of an equation using absolute value that you need help solving.

Comment: Welcome to Math.StackExchange.com! Please show what have you already found and why were your findings insufficient.

Comment: Well okay sorry I'm not a maths professor Ian Miller. What matter's is my final two questions as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 2):

we have $$|-x+3|=-x+3$$ if $$3\geq x$$
$$|-x+3|=-(-x)+3)=x-3$$ if $$3<x$$

Comment: Oh okay I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

For any function $f$, $|f(x_0)|=f(x_0)$ if and only if $f(x_0)\ge 0$; $|f(x_0)|=-f(x_0)$ if $f(x_0)\lt 0$.

On your particular occasion, doing case work, one could easily find that:

When $-x+3\ge 0\Rightarrow x\le 3, |-x+3|=-x+3$;
When $-x+3\lt 0\Rightarrow x\gt 3, |-x+3|=x-3$.

When $x+3\ge 0\Rightarrow x\ge -3, |x+3|=x+3$;
When $x+3\lt 0\Rightarrow x\lt -3, |x+3|=-x-3$.